# what is exponential generating function with n Choose k as coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, summation, exponential-function, generating-functions

> If we fix a positive integer $k$, what is the EGF of $\sum_{n=0} \binom{n}{k} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ ?

I know EGF of $\sum_{n=0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ is $e^x$, but the addition of $\binom{n}{k}$ confuses me

Comment: do you mean $\sum_{n=0} \binom{x}{n} \frac{x^n}{n!}$ ? by any chance?

Comment: no, i didn't mean that, however I think I meant $n=0$ instead of $k=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom nk\frac{x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=k}^\infty\binom nk\frac{x^n}{n!}=\frac1{k!}\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{x^n}{(n-k)!}=\frac{x^ke^x}{k!}.$$

Comment: how do you know n=k is same as n=0?

Comment: @user3427042 Because $\binom{n}{k}=0$ when $n<k$.